# dotnet new (wpf not found) Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core

```
dotnet : No templates matched the input template name: wpf.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet new wpf -o TestAppWPFCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No templates ma...late name: wpf.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with the results of running `dotnet --info`? (I've just tried this myself, and it worked fine - I'm using SDK 3.0.100-preview-010184)

Comment: Which Visual Studio 2019 version did you install? Did you include the latest 3.0 SDK? `dotnet-new` comes from the SDK, not Visual Studio. I'm also able to create both WPF and Winforms applications using `3.0.100-preview-010184`

Comment: I'm using VS2019 and 3.0.100-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed in new version of .NET CORE

Comment: Note that anybody reading this, this is Dotnet core 3+ (Currently preview). This will not work in dotnet core 2